# Black turns transparent in Blender texture

Tags: compositing-nodes

My texture has some black text (on right side of picture,) and also a transparent background. But the text also is transparent?!? Plus I must keep the text black.

Picture:[image]

Please help.

Comment: try removing that "use alpha" setting...? black is interpreted as transparency if such thing is enabled...

Comment: Try plugging the alpha output to the factor input of the mix shader, and swap shaders if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Plug the "Alpha" output in the Image Texture node to the "Factor" input in the Mix Shader node, and swap diffuse shaders if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for you help Tooniis!

I added the alpha in the mix node. And then switched the other two around.

[image]

Comment: You can put this as an update in your question, and please click that green check mark under the vote count on my answer it means that this answer is what you are looking for.